# Why won't the lucky coin drop after 69 pirate invasions?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I've done 69 invasions. And it STILL has not dropped yet. Is this a bug or glitch or am I having bad luck?

Comment: This is on Terraria mobile

Comment: Given this: 'The Lucky Coin is dropped by Pirates during a Pirate Invasion at a rate of 1/4000 (0.025%)', it's highly likely you're just unlucky.

Comment: Ok I will remember that

Comment: @Waterseas that's a fine answer you know :)

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden The issue is, its entirely speculation XD It's also very possible that its due to a glitch. There's no real way to know, thus, this question doesn't really have a valid answer.

Comment: According to math (`1-( (1-(1/4000)) ^ (120*69) )`) there is a 87% chance of it having dropped in the pirate invasions. Sounds like unlucky.

Comment: @KevinvanderVelden and to get past 50%, you have to beat 2773 mooks, yikes !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal experience was the same as yours, I did many pirate invasions to get just one lucky coin, AND just one discount card.  Ironically for me, they both dropped in the same invasion.  As @Waterseas pointed out, it is a 1/4000 chance, and yes you can be just that unlucky thanks to the mechanics of RANDOM().  On the positive side, by now you should be able to fully outfit a king's castle in golden furniture!

Comment: I remember getting 2 discount cards on 1 single invasion. [Random Number God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) was on my side that particular day.