# Why won't the discount card drop after 32 invasions?

Tags: terraria

I have been farming with my volcano type lava farm for pirate invasions.
But for some reason, I didn't drop after 32 invasions! I this a glitch, or 
Just HORRIBLE luck?

Comment: With 32 invasions and 120 pirates each the odds are about 85% for it having dropped, yeah bad luck.

Comment: My luck is always bad in terraria XD

Comment: Related?: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/221393/115226

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's probably that your having bad luck. I would suggest that you stay with your farm, but add water candles. (You can find those in the dungeon). Note it has a 1/2000 chance to drop. Check this link for more info: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Discount_Card

Answer (score -1):

The discount card is received during pirate invasions,but it is also super rare so the player doesn't go to op